# How to make Blogger QuickEdit Widget visible to administrators only?

Tags: widget, blogger, blogspot, blogger-dynamic-views

QuickEdit pencil visible to all blogger website visitors.

How do i can hide it to visitors and let the pencil visible to administrators only?

[image: click to see the picture]

When you visit the blog as a visitor the pencil is visible as shown in the picture.

Comment: Please add more information.

Comment: i 've edited the post thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add some admin CSS to your code.
Find the includable:

```
<b:includable id='postQuickEdit' var='post'>
  ...
</b:includable>
```

And add admin class:

```
<b:includable id='postQuickEdit' var='post'>
  <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:post.adminClass'>
    <a expr:href='data:post.editUrl' expr:title='data:top.editPostMsg'>Edit Post</a>
  </span>
</b:includable>
```

Comment: Thanks but i want it for widgets not for posts